# Reading formatted data from file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to write a code to read data from file. The file looks like:

```
47012   "3101 E 7TH STREET, Parkersburg, WV 26101"
48964   "S16 W22650 W. LINCOLN AVE, Waukesha, WI 53186"
.
.
.
.
```

I need to store the number as an int and the address as a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("input.txt");
long int id;
string address;
myfile >> id;
cout << id << endl;
myfile >> address;
cout << address.c_str() << endl;
myfile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The output of program

```
47012
"3101
```

The output that I need is

```
47012
3101 R 7TH STREET, Parkersburg, WV 26101
```

How do I go about doing this. Thanks in advance
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `cstring` since you're writing C++?

Comment: @crush, no, <cstring> is for C-style strings (i.e. char*).

Comment: Oh, right. Guess it's been awhile since I programmed in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `getline`:

```
while (in >> id) {
    if (!getline(in, address)) {
        // (error)
        break;
    }

    // substr from inside the quotes
    addresses[id] = address.substr(1, address.length() - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like the following. Nah, just kidding, I'd use Boost Spirit in real life. However, this seems like something you could attempt with standard library approaches too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile("input.txt");

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream linereader(line, std::ios::binary);

        long int id;

        linereader >> id;
        if (!linereader)
            throw "Expected number";

        linereader.ignore(line.size(), '"');

        string address;
        if (!std::getline(linereader, address, '"'))
            throw "Expected closing quotes";

        cout << id << endl << address << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Printing:

```
47012
3101 E 7TH STREET, Parkersburg, WV 26101
48964
S16 W22650 W. LINCOLN AVE, Waukesha, WI 53186
```

Comment: If you could explain why the OP's solution didn't work, your answer would be complete.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because the stream operator `>>` will take spaces as delimiter when trying to read strings.

You could use `getline(stream, address, '\t');` to read a string with a specific delimiter.

Or simply `getline(stream, address)` if there is nothing else to read on that line :

```
long int id;
string address;
myfile >> id;
getline(stream, address);
```

This is just an example, see *@not-sehe*'s answer for a complete solution (read the lines using `getline` and then parse each line using a `stringstream`).

Comment: Doing that results in the following address: {space} " 3101 R 7TH STREET, Parkersburg, WV 26101" 
How do I get rid of the space and quotes and just get the address to the string?

Comment: @user62089: use `substr` then.

Comment: @zakinster: To remove quotes the following worked:
address.erase(remove(address.begin(),address.end(), '\"'),address.end());
How do I remove the space in front

Comment: @user62089: `find_first_not_of`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cin.getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) which will read the remainder of the line.

First read the digit, then use getline() to read everything remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operator terminates a string at a space.I would recommend using

```
char temp[100];
myfile.getline(temp,max_length);
```

This reads a line at a time.Then you can use a loop to split the line in the way you want.

I would like to add that you might need the `atoi(char *)`(from module `cytpe.h`) function to convert an integer string to an integer.

Comment: You do not need `atoi` to read an `int` from an `istream`, the `operator<<` can perfectly handle that.

Comment: But the buffer is a string..Wont that need an atoi?I answered with the point of C rather than C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getline(myfile, address, '"');//dummy read skip first '"'
    getline(myfile, address, '"');
```